# Translating Lightbend activator to sbt

Tags: sbt, typesafe-activator

I'm trying to work through the book Reactive Web Applications, but it seems that it's already a bit out of date in that lightbend activator has been EOL'd so I can't download it (or at least can't figure out how to and probably shouldn't even if I could).

I'm faced with the problem of creating the new project, which in the book would be done via the command

```
activator new twitter-stream play-scala-2.4
```

I tried what I though was the equivalent `sbt` command but got the following error.

```
urban:playground dhosek$ sbt new playframework/play-scala-seed.g8
[info] Set current project to playground (in build         
file:/Users/dhosek/playground/)
[error] Not a valid command: new (similar: set)
[error] Not a valid project ID: new
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: new (similar: name, run, runner)
[error] new
[error]    ^
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the problem is that brew installs an old version of sbt.

Comment: Indeed, this is the correct answer, you need to update sbt in order to use the new command.